# Element not displaying as block

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes that in a normal desktop viewport they display in an inline fashion. My issue is when in a 640 viewport or less I cannot get the boxes to `display: block;` . I have tried putting the `display: block` in the `.box` class and the individual color ids. What happens is the boxes overlap and lay on each other.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong in my attempt?

```
<section id="info">
          <article>
            <a href="projects"><div id="green" class="box">
                <div class="info-box-title">PROJECTS</div>
                <div class="info-box-description">Over 60 years of accumulated projects.</div>
            </div></a>
            <a href="about"><div id="yellow" class="box">
                <div class="info-box-title">ABOUT US</div>
                <div class="info-box-description">Find out about - The Eslich Wrecking Company.</div>
            </div></a>
            <a href="contact"><div id="red" class="box">
                <div class="info-box-title">CONTACT US</div>
                <div class="info-box-description">Contact us for more information.</div>
            </div></a>
          </article>
        </section>
```

Default CSS

```
#info {
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 10%;
    margin: 100px 10%;
}
.box {
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
#green, #yellow, #red {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
#green {
    background: #3e745b;
    left: 15%;

}
#yellow {
    background: #6f9697;/*#f3db6d*/
    left: 40%;
}
#red {
    background: #3e745b;
    left: 65%;
}
#green:hover, #yellow:hover, #red:hover {
    /*box-shadow: inset 0 300px 0 0 #6f9697;*/
    box-shadow: inset 0 300px 0 0 #303030;
}
#green.green{animation:slideinGreen .5s ease}
#yellow.yellow{animation:slideinYellow 1.3s ease}
#red.red{animation:slideinRed 2s ease}
#green.active,#red.active,#yellow.active{opacity: 1}
@keyframes slideinGreen {
  from {
    left: calc(25% - 250px);opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes slideinYellow{
  from {
    left: calc(45% - 350px);opacity:0;
  }
}
@keyframes slideinRed {
  from {
    left: calc(65% - 450px);opacity:0;
  }
}
```

Media query of 640px or less

```
/*---Fade In Boxes---*/
#info {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0%;
    margin: 0;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    display: block;
}
#green {
    left: 0%;
}
#yellow {
    left: 0%;
}
#red {
    left: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Do you get rid of the absolute positioning too?

Comment: It's not technically compliant to wrap an `<a>` element around `<div>` elements.

Comment: @cale_b How else would you recommend to do it to get the whole box to be a link then?

Comment: @j08691 That did it! Not sure why I overlooked that. Leave an answer.

Comment: @cale_b - I'm pretty sure in HTML5 that's fine.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with those boxes with the link because the 2nd and 3rd boxes when hovering over them show blue for a second like the link it showing. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @j08691 - Yes, you are right, however it still feels "wrong" to me for some reason.  Probably years of coding against HTML4 standards....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your absolute positioning on the box class is causing the issue. The elements are overlapping one another because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Change position of `.box` to relative:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 .box {
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   display: block;
```

}

Because `#home-info-container` have `padding: 100px 15%`, 3 boxes can full width. If you want full with for 3 boxes, and keep padding ofdescription:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #home-info-container {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }

   #home-info-container-description {
      padding-left: 15%;
      padding-right: 15%;
   }
 }
```